# How to run an .animate immediately after fancybox function

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to open a `fancybox` then run an animation on a z-indexed item. I want the .animate function to run automatically after the `fancybox` has opened.

to open a fancybox: `$("#box").fancybox()`

What I need to do is

```
$("#box").fancybox({
   $("#box").animate({left: "200"}, slow) 
});
```

But this clearly won't work.  I am still learning jquery and js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox has an [`onComplete`](http://fancybox.net/api) callback.

```
var box = $("#box")
box.fancybox({
  'onComplete': function() { box.animate({left: "200"}, slow); }
});
```

Comment: So the code doesn't run the animate but it helps put me in the right direction.

Comment: @TJ Please don't use the comments for adding large code blocks. You are probably better off asking a new question.